# How to write this simple matlab script to create a matrix from another matrix.

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix $A= \pmatrix{
    0 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
}$
and I wish to add another matrix B which has the row entries $d_i= 1$ (vector of all 1's) if the ith row of A is $0$ and $d_i=0$ otherwise.

I'm unsure how to write a script for this. I can do it manually row by row but wish to learn a quicker more efficient way which I'll be able to build upon.

Edit: I forgot to include I wish the row of 1's on B to be 1/n where n is the dimension so here n=6.
Thanks

Comment: you mean if the $i$th row of $A$ contains only $0$'s?

Comment: Yes, if the ith row contains only 0's i.e is the 0 row vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kron(sum(abs(A)')'==0,ones(1,length(A)))/length(A)`

Comment: you're welcome to Math.StackExchange. Remind that StackOverflow also has a [(Matlab)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag...

Answer (score 1):

I think draks' method is better. I did

```
x = sum(abs(A),2) == 0
B = repmat(x,size(x'))
```

If you're not worried about negative entries, you can replace abs(A) by A.

Comment: +1 for taking care of negative entries. You don't mind if I include this in mine as well?

Comment: Of course not. Aside: i) is there any way to store x as a temporary variable so that I don't have store it in memory? ii) which of the two (your way or mine) is more computationally efficient? I know next to nothing about MATLAB but want to learn.

Comment: just insert your first into the second `B = repmat((sum(abs(A),2) == 0),size((sum(abs(A),2) == 0)'))`. I've no idea which of these is more efficient. I guess they are quite comparable in runtime...